# How to refer static variables in the same class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo {

    private static temp: Number;

    public static testIt() {
        this.temp = 0;// Var 1
        Foo.temp = 0;// Var 2
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors from TS when I compile this class. Does it mean that both variants are possible to refer static variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, although I wouldn't use the first.

The reason the first one works is because `this` in a function is set to whatever came before the dot operator. That is

```
Foo.testIt()
^^^ <- this will be Foo
```

This roundabout way is confusing in a sense that you expect `this` to be an instance, but there's no instance here.

---

In conclusion, the two are almost always equivalent, but I would still use `Foo` over `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both versions refer to the static field inside a static method. Inside a static method `this` refers to the current object the method is being invoked on which will be the class.

Be careful though if you assign the static method to a different variable, `this` will no longer refer to the class (since the method will not be invoked on the class). The class named access will work regardless of how the method is called.

```
class Foo {

    private static temp: Number = 1;

    public static testIt() {
        console.log(this.temp)
        console.log(Foo.temp)
    }
}

Foo.testIt(); // Outputs 1, 1 

let m = Foo.testIt;
m(); // Outputs undefined, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Both way are correct

- when you run `Foo.testIt()` **this** will refer to `Foo`
- Foo.temp will look on current to global scope for variable named `Foo` (lexical scope) and try to update his property temp to zero

this way `this` point to another object rather than Foo

```
Foo.testIt.call({}); => undefined , zero
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a superset to verify if your code types are logically consistent (type checking), it does not verify if your code is good practice or what it does. So it will compile as this code type checking is valid.

So what does this code do?

Foo.temp means the variable in the Foo Class

this.temp means the variable in the instance of the Foo Class.